# Why does bazel's rules_foreign_cc make not find/create the artifacts?

Tags: gnu-make, bazel

I want to create a `make` rule from `rules_foreign_cc`.
But even the minimal example below is causing issues for me.

With the following setup:

```
.
├── BUILD (empty)
├── hello
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── hello.c
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── WORKSPACE (empty)
└── WORKSPACE
```

`WORKSPACE`:

```
workspace(name = "test")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    sha256 = "2a4d07cd64b0719b39a7c12218a3e507672b82a97b98c6a89d38565894cf7c51",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-0.9.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/refs/tags/0.9.0.tar.gz",
)
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

# This sets up some common toolchains for building targets. For more details, please see
# https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/0.9.0/flatten.html#rules_foreign_cc_dependencies
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()

local_repository(
    name = "hello",
    path = "hello",
)
```

`hello/BUILD.bazel`:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "make")

filegroup(
  name = "hellosrc",
  srcs =  glob([
    "**",
  ]),
)

make(
    name="hello_build",
    lib_source=":hellosrc",
    out_bin_dir="",
    out_binaries=["hello_binary"],
    targets=["all"],
)
```

`hello/Makefile`:

```
all:
    gcc hello.c -o hello_binary

clean:
    rm hello
```

`hello/hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and running

```
bazel build @hello//:hello_build
```

I'm getting

```
INFO: Analyzed target @hello//:hello_build (43 packages loaded, 812 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/timotheus/.cache/bazel/_bazel_timotheus/a791a0a19ff4a5d2730aa0c8954985c4/external/hello/BUILD.bazel:10:5: output 'external/hello/hello_build/hello_binary' was not created
ERROR: /home/timotheus/.cache/bazel/_bazel_timotheus/a791a0a19ff4a5d2730aa0c8954985c4/external/hello/BUILD.bazel:10:5: Foreign Cc - Make: Building hello_build failed: not all outputs were created or valid
Target @hello//:hello_build failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 12.426s, Critical Path: 12.22s
INFO: 7 processes: 5 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Basically, I have no idea where Bazel is looking for the created binaries (are they even created?). I tried to set `out_bin_dir` to different values or not set it at all, all with the same effect.

I expect Bazel to generate the binary and find it - or at least give me a hint what it does.

Answer (score 0):

And I think I found the solution.
make of rules_foreign_cc expects that the make project has an install target.
If that's not the case, it doesn't find the binaries.

This is how I could fix my minimal example - adding an install target to the Makefile

```
install:
    cp -rpv hello_binary $(PREFIX)
```

Comment: Yes you must run a target that does an equivalent of `make install`, *and* you must set your build up so that it moves the artifacts you want to get into `$$INSTALLDIR$$`, a directory that bazel gives you. The rule will assume that your binary outputs are in `$INSTALLDIR/bin`, and your libraries in `$INSTALLDIR/lib`. You can use the other parameters of the `make` target to change that if you have a "nonstandard" make file. I now documented it at https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/main/make.html, can you take a look and see if it helps you any?

Answer (score 0):

In case it is useful, I wrote [a fully worked out example and explanation](https://hdlfactory.com/post/2023/06/13/how-to-use-the-make-rule-from-rules_foreign_cc-repository-for-bazel/). And, your conclusion that you *must* do an equivalent of `make install` is correct.